# Recommended max photo size for full screen width, responsive slideshow

Tags: image, max, slideshow, image-size

I build responsive sites for the travel industry and our clients are definitely wanting to follow the trend of having HUGE photo slideshows to show off their local area.  These slideshows take up the full width of the browser.

I am looking for a recommended maximum pixel width for the images that get uploaded to these slideshows (FYI I'm using the plugin Camera for WordPress).  A client recently asked me this because he is concerned about load time, and I've certainly considered this on my own before, but haven't ever come to a solid conclusion (and I haven't found anything yet in my hours of searching already).  For example, on one site I have uploaded photos that are each 1700x565 pixels.  But the files are over 200K each!  Admittedly, I could probably optimize it a bit better, but you can only optimize to a certain point without losing quality.

I have two concerns:

1) What about the users who are on really big resolutions, like 1920px or larger?  The photo is going to get pixelated when it grows responsively with the resolution from 1700px to 1920px (or whatever).

2) What about load time for desktop users?  (I'm not planning on loading the slideshow at all for mobile devices, so that's a non-issue).  I don't want to end up with a really crappy Google page speed score.

Are there any best practices regarding this issue?  Any articles on this you could refer me to?

Answer (score 0):

Surprised this hasn't been answered but I will do my best.

Rule of thumb for image optimization for the web & code, in my training, has been to upload the image size preferred and to adjust per device using media queries 
( more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries ).

Typically, I've been taught to keep my file sizes to about 50-70kb(dependent on format) but the lower the number the better. Shopify's article on image optimization says it best:

http://www.shopify.com/blog/7412852-10-must-know-image-optimization-tips#axzz2hk4NxlaN

Hope this helped!